# Function not working as expected in PHP

Tags: php

What is wrong with the output of this function, it prints out INF int the browser where as 
I expected it to print out 654321
The exact same function written in C# print out the expected result.

```
<?php
        function reverse($n, $r){
            if($n == 0) {
                return $r;
            }
            return reverse($n/10, $r*10 + $n%10);
        }

        echo reverse(123456, 0);
?>
```

Comment: Well, PHP is not C#. If you want to reverse a string (or a number) just use the built-in `strrev`.

Comment: try `reverse((int)($n/10), $r*10 + ($n%10));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not do integer division. In C# you deal with strict typing, and when you divide 25 by 4 in C# you will get integer result, 6. In php you will get 6.25, float result.

Try `intval` your results before recursion to get integer division

Comment: Thank you,this is the answer is expected

Comment: @juice then please click on the tick mark symbol visible below the voting symbol of this answer

Answer (score 2):

Try the [`strrev()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php) function:

```
strrev('123456'); //654321
```